# how to remove borders for a particular table cells in html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, border, html-table, cells

i am having the following markup.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-stripped width_setting">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
      <th>Posted On</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="remove_border_th"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @jobpostings.each do |jobposting| %>
      <tr>
    <td><%= jobposting.S_No %></td>
    <td><%= jobposting.Job_Title %></td>
    <td><%= jobposting.Posted_On %></td>
    <td><%= jobposting.CTC %></td>
    <!-- <td><%#= link_to 'View Details', assessment %></td> -->
    <td class="no_border_2" ><%= link_to 'View Details',  jobposting, :target => "_blank" %>&nbsp;</td>
    <!-- <td><%#= link_to 'Apply', edit_assessment_path(assessment) %></td> -->
    <td class="no_border_1"><%= link_to 'Apply', :controller=>"job_applicants", :action=>"new", :title=> jobposting.Job_Title %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br>

<%= link_to "Home", :controller=>"jobpostings", :action=>"index" %> |<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete %>


<style type="text/css">

    .width_setting {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  width: 813px;
}
.no_border_2{
border-right:none !important;

border-bottom:none !important;

border-top: none !important;
}


.no_border_1{
border-right:none !important;
border-left:none !important;
border-bottom:none !important;
border-top: none !important;

}
.remove_border_th{
border-right:none !important;

border-bottom:none !important;
border-top: none !important;

}

</style>
```

i am getting the following output with this current mark up.

[image]

i want to remove the border for the cells for these links ,`View Details`,`apply` on all sides(top, right, bottom, left). how can i do that? please help me.i tried all the possible options related to border cells, still the issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove the border would be to use a nested table.

```
<table>
 <table class="TableWithBorder">
  <!--Content-->
 </table>
 <table class="TableWithoutBorder">
  <!--Links-->
 </table>
</table>
```